# Phusion Passenger - SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, passenger

After finally resolving the `Unexpected token: import` when using `import Vue from 'vue';` by using `const Vue = require('vue');`, the following error occurred when deploying to the server.
It looks like its trying to import a css file as javascript, but I have no clue why this is happening and would very much like some help figuring this out!

If you have any knowledge on getting es6 features to work in Passenger I would love to hear them as well!

```
node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css:10
.btn-social{position:relative;padding-left:44px;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}.btn-social>:first-child{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;width:32px;line-height:34px;font-size:1.6em;text-align:center;border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Object.vm.runInThisContext (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:117:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:613:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
```

Node version: `v8.14.0`

Comment: It seems like the problem actually happens before that. This is just where it found the first error, so if I am not mistaken, without further detail would be hard for anybody to help you. Good luck :)

Comment: @PedroFerrari locally it runs perfect, only on the server it fails to serve. What details would you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by importing the css files in my `build.scss` using `@import "../../node_modules/path_to_css_file"`